# React Native dynamically require(images)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, require

I'm programming an App similar to coinmarketcap.com.
A giant list of up to 700 coins and icons etc in a SectionList. But in my App, you can choose which coins you wanna track.

Is there a way to not require ALL 700 icons but just selected ones ?
Right now I have an objects.js file with:

```
export const IMAGES = {
  'btc-usd': require('../icons/bitcoin.png'), //statically analyzed
  'eth-usd': require('../icons/ether.png'),
   ...
```

But I'm worried about memory and performance. Does React load them all in RAM ? Or just when it renders ?
Thanks a lot for helping

Found this solution but not sure if it is technically more efficient:

> A simple solution I found was creating a very minimalistic
>   package.json inside the top-most folder you want to absolutely import
>   from. That package.json should look like this: { "name": "src" },
>   where "src" is the name of that folder.
>
> The you can simply do import X from 'src/X.js' just as you would
>   normally do.

[Source](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/3099)

Thanks a lot for helping!

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: not yet. Will post the answer if I find one

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a [FlatList](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html)? It will only render items in view as well as a few items ahead. It should give you the performance boost you seek. As for lazily requiring/loading images, maybe use a package like [react-native-lazyload](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-lazyload).

Comment: it's true what you say. SectionList is like FlatList, just with Sections. Gonna check out lazyload, thanks! My technical question as well as how to load dynamically (through tricks) remains